# Python 3.6 & Inserting Values into MariaDB via variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, mariadb

Code description - Running a program to add values to a maria db table. The program executes and prompts for the variables without error but the table shows no rows when I query it. Any idea where I am going wrong? Wanted to make it dynamic so I am using variables for the db and the table.
     ######## Output #########

```
[root@localhost student_program]# python db_setup.py
Connection successful!!
Database already exists: students
create_table
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:329: Warning: (1050, " Table 'students_info' already exists")
  self._do_get_result()
use students;
Enter the first name :Frank
Enter the last name: Brady
Enter the email address: frank@noemail.com
Enter the address: 300 Main Street, Belfast
Enter the DOB in YYYY-MM-DD: 1980-02-02
Enter the english mark: 90
Enter the maths mark: 80
Enter the history mark: 70
Enter the science mark: 45
('INSERT into students_info (firstname, lastname,email,address,DOB,english,maths,history,science) VALUES  (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);', ('Frank', 'Brady', 'frank@noemail.com', '300 Main Street, Belfast', '1980-02-02', '90', '80', '70', '45'))


######### Program below #################

     import os,pymysql

    mariadb_root = '/var/lib/mysql/'

    db_to_create = 'students'

    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',  user='xxx', passwd='xxx',  cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    print('Connection successful!!')


# Check if db exists, if not create

def check_db_exists():
    dbfile = os.path.join(mariadb_root, db_to_create)
    if not os.path.exists(dbfile):
        cur = conn.cursor()
        command = "CREATE DATABASE %s;" % db_to_create
        print(command)
        cur.execute(command)
        print("Database created %s:", db_to_create)
    else:
        print("Database already exists: %s" % db_to_create)
check_db_exists()

def create_database():
    cur = conn.cursor()
    command = "use %s; " %db_to_create
    cur.execute(command)
    create_table = ("""
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students_info (
                ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                firstname varchar(255),
                lastname varchar(255),
                email varchar(255),
                address varchar(255),
                DOB DATE,
                english varchar(255),
                maths varchar(255),
                history varchar(255),
                science varchar(255),
                PRIMARY KEY (ID));
                """)
    print("create_table")
    cur.execute(create_table)
    print(command)

create_database()

def add_student():
    firstname = input("Enter the first name :")
    lastname = input("Enter the last name: ")
    email = input("Enter the email address: ")
    address = input("Enter the address: ")
    DOB = input("Enter the DOB in YYYY-MM-DD: ")
    english = input("Enter the english mark: ")
    maths = input("Enter the maths mark: ")
    history = input("Enter the history mark: ")
    science = input("Enter the science mark: ")

    cur = conn.cursor()
    command = "use %s; " %db_to_create
    cur.execute(command)

    cur.execute = ("""INSERT into students_info (firstname, lastname,email,address,DOB,english,maths,history,science) VALUES  (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);""",
    (firstname,lastname,email,address, DOB,english,maths,history,science))
    print(cur.execute)

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
add_student()
```

Comment: I've just tried that, after the cur.execute, and the table is still empty when I query it..

Comment: Added a commit towards the end and the table is still empty when queried. The last 4 lines are now 
 conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
add_student()